# How to get absolute paths from FileDialog from different folders

Tags: java, gtk, swt

One way to open multiple files in SWT is to use a FileDialog:

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.MULTI);
dialog.open();

System.out.println(dialog.getFilterPath());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dialog.getFileNames()));
```

and each filename can be concatenated with the filter path.

This works except for when the files are in different folders as given by "Recently Used" or "Search" in the dialog (GTK version). The filter path ends up being correct for only some of the files.

For example, if the paths are:

```
/path1/file1
/path2/file2
```

filterPath is 'path1', and fileNames is [file1, file2], so 'path2' is missing.

Is there any way to get the correct paths in this case, or any alternative in SWT?

Comment: +1 Very good question, I couldn't find any solution for it. Looking forward to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean multiple file selection, there is no 'good' way.

I looked online and founded

> The only way I know how to do something like that (there is probably a better way) is to allow multiple files to be selected and then getSelectedFiles(File[] someName) throws them into an array of files.

And i founded it at [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/331877/GUI/java/FileDialog-multiple-file-selection)

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug, that is also affecting other systems (see [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=267502))

for now I decided to check all file paths with `File.exists()` and throw a checked exception if any path is invalid.

this solution is not safe though and can lead to opening wrong files, if you have files with same names but different paths.

another solution would be to disable multiple file selection or do some really ugly hack with `FileDialog`

sadly at the moment it's a question of how much you trust your users not to screw up their file selection